# Character set conversion problem - debug invalid characters - reverse engineer earlier conversions

Tags: debugging, character-encoding, char, non-ascii-characters, file-conversion

Character conversion problem.
I have a few strings which are incorrectly encoded or decoded.
The strings came in an ASCII format CSV file.

The current strings I have are:

```
N‚met
Tet‹
```

I know, that the:

```
"‚" character (0x82) should be originally "é" (é acute accent)
"‹" character (0x8B) should be originally "ő" (o double acute accent)
```

How can I debug and reverse engineer, what conversions happened with the original characters to get the current characters?

I suppose that multiple decoding encoding happened, but I was not able to reproduce the original character.

Comment: Your viewer uses 1252 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), and your original input some other coding, probably based on DOS 437: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437 You may check the CP on page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding): the most common ones. Maybe 852 (Central European).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: You are right. Please post as answer I will accept it. I tested with the following site: http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx Enter: "ő", select IBM852 as Encode, select Windows-1252. Result will be: "‹". Enter: "é", select IBM852 as Encode, select Windows-1252. Result will be: ",". Thank you very much!

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: However I was not able to reverse the result from "," to "é". Is it possible?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: Simply it is DOS CP852 code page text, which is displayed in Windows environment, Windows-1252 encoding. Please post this as answer, I will accept it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put an expanded version of my comment as answer:

Your viewer uses [CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (English and Western Europe, also called ANSI in Windows) or [CP1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) (Eastern Europe) or an other similar code page. Most of characters are coded in the same manner, just few language specific changes. Your example do not includes character that are different on the two encoding, so I cannot say precisely.

That code pages are used on Microsoft Windows, and they are based (but not 100% compatible) with Latin-1, so it is common to see text interpreted with such encoding. MacOs and Linux are heavily (now) UTF-8 encoded. Windows uses Unicode internally (but UTF-16)

The old encoding is probably CP437: the standard code page in DOS, so it was used frequently also for CSV files. Other frequent old encoding are CP850 (Western Europe) and CP852 (Central Europe).

For the other answers you put in the comments, I think you should go to Superuser (if you are requesting tools (some editors allow you to specify the encoding. You may use the browser (opening a local file): browsers also allow you to choose the local encoding, and I think you may copy as Unicode [not sure], other tools sometime has hidden option to import files, but possibly not with all options), or as new question in this site, if you want to do it programmatically. But so you are required to specify the language. Python is well suited for such conversions (most scripting languages are created to handle texts): python has built in many encoding, you should just specify when reading and when writing the files. R also can be instructed on the input encoding.

Comment: Thanks! Your guidance helped me to, so I accept this answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own utility that helped me to diagnose and fix many thorny encoding issues. It is available as part of an Open source library. The utility converts any String to unicode sequence and vise-versa. All you will have to do is:

```
String codes = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence("Hello world");
```

And it will return String `"\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064"`

The same would work for any String in any language including special characters. Here is the link to the article [Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing Unicode converter and Version comparison](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/) that explains about the library and where to get it (available both on [Maven central](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.michaelgantman%7CMgntUtils%7C1.5.0.2%7Cjar) and [github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt). In the article search for paragraph: **"String Unicode converter"**.

So when you read your String convert it and see what comes up. This way you will see what symbols are there and if the info is correct and only distorted by some wrong encoding or the info itself is lost. You can easily find info on internet that provides tables of mapping of any symbol to a unicode

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer to the question. Are you asking the question author to run the tool to add more information to the question?

Comment: Not exactly. I am offering a tool that if run may shad the light on the problem and clarify if the data is there but just displayed incorrectly or the data itself is corrupted/lost. So the tool meant to diagnose the problem. It helped me numerous times. But OP may run the tool and provide the results and then I or someone else can help him to continue to analyze the issue

Comment: Sure, but as not answer, it would be better as a comment and/or listed in a tag wiki.

Comment: @Tom - I understand your point but disagree: The content of the question does not have enough of info to give definitive answer. My answer provides a way to get that info and very possible to resolve it as well. So I feel it is justified to stay as an answer. But this is of course my opinion